# Silverlight 5 player to test Silverlight 4 apps safe?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-5.0

Is it safe to install the Silverlight 5 player when I'm testing Silverlight 4 apps? Could compatbility issues pop up or bugs in Silverlight 4 which won't appear in 5 or if I install Silverlight 5 it will still use the Silverlight 4 player for Silverlight 4 content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on what you're doing.

If you're working on a media player of DRM-protected videos for instance, it's not quite safe: https://blogs.msdn.com/b/playready4/archive/2011/12/08/playready-license-acquisition-fails-after-upgrading-to-silverlight-5.aspx?Redirected=true

Answer (score 1):

You should have no problems with that. Just go ahead and install Silverligh 5

Comment: Just make sure you install the developer/debug version if you are developing and not the browser update :)

Answer (score 1):

Classically,
backward compaitablity problems may occur. Such as we use some 3rd party components they behave diffrent in silverlight 4 and silverlight 5. But minor problems we had.

On design time there are some other problems with **Silverlight 5 because it uses .Net Framework 4.5** so there are some changes between 4.5 and 4.0. These changeset cause some design time problems. i.e. you can't view your XAML design if you use MVVM pattern for some Graphical components.

Have a look at http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/silverlight/chart/adding-radchart-in-visual-studio-designer.aspx#1946980 
and https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/708140/silverlight-forum-mefedmvvm-design-time-feature-doesnt-work-in-silverlight-5

The error says that **'System.Delegate System.Reflection.MethodInfo.CreateDelegate(System.Type, System.Object)**

this method exist on Framework 4.5 not in 4.0.

As a result you cant guarantee the compaitablity because of the frameworks diffrence.